# Automatically select item added to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, observablecollection

I am trying to automatically select an item in a ListView whenever one is added to an ObservableCollection. I am using the CollectionChanged event to listen for when an item is added and then select it. The CollectionChanged event seems to occur before the UI is updated and so the SelectedIndex is adjusted accordingly. I have tried setting both the SelectedIndex and the SelectedItem but in both cases the item after the one added ends up being selected. The correct index is the when the collection is changed, the UI updates and then the the index is incremented by the ListView.

The phenomenon can be demonstrated with the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding Main, Source= {StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0">
        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="Add Item" Width="75" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}"/>
            <Label Content="SelectedIndex:"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding SelectedIndex}"/>
            <Label Content="SelectedItem:"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
            <Label Content="&lt;- Numbers should match after item added"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ICommand addItemCommand;
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private int selectedIndex = -1;
    public const string SelectedIndexPropertyName = "SelectedIndex";
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedIndex != value)
            {
                selectedIndex = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedIndexPropertyName);
            }
        }
    }

    private string selectedItem = null;
    public const string SelectedItemPropertyName = "SelectedItem";
    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedItem != value)
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedItemPropertyName);
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> items;
    public const string ItemsPropertyName = "Items";
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ItemsPropertyName);
        }
    }

    private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            //SelectedItem = e.NewItems[0];
            SelectedIndex = e.NewStartingIndex;
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (addItemCommand == null)
                addItemCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Items.Add("Item " + items.Count));

            return addItemCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

I have added uploaded a example solution to [www.itzalive.co.uk/AddItemSelection.zip](http://www.itzalive.co.uk/AddItemSelection.zip)

Anybody know how to end up with the newly added item selected using the CollectionChanged event? In my actual program the item is not added in the same place it is being displayed so it is not possible to set the selected item separately.

Comment: Where is your SelectedItem property in C#?

Comment: Didn't include it as it wasn't being used it essentially looks exactly the same as the SelectedIndex property

Comment: Both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` bind the same thing, so I don't recommend setting both at once. Does it work if you remove your `SelectedItem` binding?

Comment: I have made sure that I am only ever changing one or the other of the two properties in code so there is no interference between them.

Comment: And no, only binding to one or the other doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to use just the `SelectedItem` property, rather than the `SelectedIndex` property as well:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
```

Then in code:

```
YourClass newItem = new YourClass();
Items.Add(newItem);
SelectedItem = newItem;
```

Also remove your code from the `Items_CollectionChanged` event handler. You may also need to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");` to get the UI to update if it doesn't already.

---

UPDATE >>>

Try adding this into your `CollectionChanged` handler then:

```
if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add) 
    SelectedItem = e.NewItems[0] as string;
```

Comment: I am trying to be able to do it so that the item can be added to the list anywhere and it will be selected. This means I can't select the item in the following line to where I add it.

Comment: I have also previously tried that however I get the same result. It seems that the CollectionChanged event happens whilst the data and UI are out of sync and so some strange updates occur.

Comment: I can't tell you what's wrong with code that you haven't shown me. Please read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page from the Help Center to find out how to create an appropriate code example and then edit your question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error was with something already listed. I have edited the question though with a complete set of code that can be used to replicate the phenomenon for ease.

Comment: Well, thank you for wasting my time. Can you tell me what the very first line of my answer says? Did you take my advice? No you didn't, and *that* is why the rest of my answer did not work for you. REMOVE THE `SelectedIndex` PROPERTY and my answer will work. It's very frustrating when I try to help but users don't listen.

Comment: Apologies I honestly thought I had tried that. Why does binding to both cause errors even if one only one of them is ever set?

Comment: To answer that, you'll need to look into the code of the .NET assemblies to see the connection.